# Using a Switch() widget with GetX/Obx()

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am back with the question: How can I use the Switch() widget with GetX/Obx()?
At many places i have read that with GetX/Obx no need of StatefullWidget. So in my app I use  only StatelessWidgets. Problem is that i can not make a Switch() working because SetState() is not usable in StatelessWidget.

Can someone help, please?
Thank for your kindness.
A.KOTE

Answer (score 10):

## GetX + Switch

Here's a copy/paste example of using GetX with a `Switch` widget, within a `StatelessWidget`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

/// GetX Controller for holding Switch's current value
class SwitchX extends GetxController {
  RxBool on = false.obs; // our observable

  // swap true/false & save it to observable
  void toggle() => on.value = on.value ? false : true;
}

/// Stateless Page here
class SwitchGetxPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SwitchX sx = Get.put(SwitchX()); // Instantiate Get Controller, *in* build()

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Switch Field'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              // Obx will rebuild Text & Switch when "on" observable changes
              Obx(() => Text('Switch Setting: ${sx.on}')),
              Obx(() => Switch(
                onChanged: (val) => sx.toggle(), 
                value: sx.on.value),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### GetX + State

With GetX you don't need `StatefulWidgets` because you're holding "state" outside of widgets and "inside" a `GetxController`.

In the example above, `RxBool on = false.obs` is the "state" of your application.  It will be `true` or `false` throughout the life of your app.

When `Switch's` value changes, any widgets you need rebuilt, put them in `Obx`, `GetX` or `GetBuilder` and use the observable variable.

`Obx`, `GetX` will rebuild themselves whenever their observable changes.  `GetBuilder` requires you call `update()` for it to rebuild. Just like a `setState()` call.

#### Why Two `Obx` in Example?

To make painfully obvious that `Obx/GetX` must directly wrap an observable variable.

`GetX` asks you to use observable variables directly in `Obx/GetX`, not further nested down, like in child of a child.

For example, this below, will throw an Error:

```
class SwitchGetxPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SwitchX sx = Get.put(SwitchX());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Switch Field'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Obx(() => MyTextSwitch(sx)), // don't do this, will explode
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyTextSwitch extends StatelessWidget {
  final SwitchX sx;

  MyTextSwitch(this.sx);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text('Switch Setting: ${sx.on}'),
        Switch(
            onChanged: (val) => sx.toggle(),
            value: sx.on.value)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This version below is still OK, but not used in first example, as it may lead to bad habits (like rebuilding widgets that don't need it) & errors like the example immediately above.  Just remember that `Obx/GetX` must have an observable in its child:

```
class SwitchGetxPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SwitchX sx = Get.put(SwitchX());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Switch Field'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Obx( // still OK, but rebuilds Column unnecessarily
            () => Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Switch Setting: ${sx.on}'),
                Switch(
                    onChanged: (val) => sx.toggle(),
                    value: sx.on.value)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your Getx sx.toggle() needs an update function like: sx.toggle.update((val)=>print(val))

Comment: @OsamaBuzdar Can you explain what `toggle()` needs an update function for?

Answer (score 1):

For simple Switch state toggle you should not use a controller. Controller is for more complex business logic implementation which can be shared among screens. You can use `ValueBuilder` from `Get` package which can give desired result with less code. Here is an example :

```
Center(
          child: ValueBuilder<bool>(
            initialValue: true,
            builder: (isChecked, updateFn) => Switch(
              value: isChecked,
              onChanged: (newValue) => updateFn(newValue),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Hi Sahoo, this is OK, it works !!! Thanks very much. Is it possible to use the same method for Radio buttons (I mean radioListTile)?

Comment: Yes, any widget that requires to have a local state can be done easily this way as long as you are using GetX package.

Comment: it's throwing an error: `Expected a value of type '(bool?, (bool?) => void) => Widget', but got one of type '(bool, (bool) => void) => Switch'`

Comment: The answer was before the null safe was introduced but now needs to be tweaked to be null-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example and then you can implement in your code.

You can use a GetxController to handle the widget state.

Counter example:

```
class YourController extends GetxController {
  //The current value
  int counter = 0;

  void increment() {
    counter++;
    update(); // use update() to update counter variable on UI when increment be called
  }
}
```

Then in your statelessWidget you can listen.

```
class YourWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: GetBuilder<YourController>(
        init: Controller(), // INIT IT ONLY THE FIRST TIME
        builder: (_) => Text(
          '${_.counter}',
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

DOCS: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md#simple-state-manager

How can you update the value?

Add a line to your controller

```
class YourController extends GetxController {
      //New line added
      static YourController  get to => Get.find();
      int counter = 0;

      void increment() {
        counter++;
        update(); // use update() to update counter variable on UI when increment be called
      }
    }
```

Update the UI

```
return Scaffold(
      // body: /*... */
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Hit'),
        onPressed: () {
          //Apply the logic to your Switch widget
          YourController.to.update();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi Rolando, Thanks very much for your help. Your example is clear to me and I already use the same format in my code. My real problem is: I have a Switch widget in a StatelessWidget. How can I obtain it switching ON/OFF ? I guess it will be possible when I use GetX/Obx(). But I do not know how?