# wrapping Custom Object with Obx() throw error. is there way to achieve this thing properly. without changing custom widget from stateless to statefull

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a stateless custom widget whose value needs to be changed according to the selection. I tried to wrap my custom object with OBX() I am receiving an error...
**[Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx
or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
(example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.**
What's the proper way to achieve reactiveness.

Comment: pass the value as an argument in cosntructor of your child stateless widget

Comment: yes, this is what am doing.  I pass the Obx value as an argument in the child constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I find and its resolves my issue.

To make it painfully obvious that Obx/GetX must directly wrap an observable variable.

GetX asks you to use observable variables directly in Obx/GetX, not further nested down, like in child of a child.

the answer is taken by this [Using a Switch() widget with GetX/Obx()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65298416/using-a-switch-widget-with-getx-obx?rq=1). this guy explains it well I hope it helps somebody.